# How to delete duplicate rows in Kusto?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I have a table in Kusto that has some duplicates, which I can determine as each unique record will have a unique `Key` column. I figured a simple way to delete duplicates would be with a command like this:

```
.delete table TABLENAME records <| TABLENAME
| summarize MaxIngestionTime = max(ingestion_time()) by Key
| join kind=inner (TABLENAME) on Key
| where ingestion_time() != MaxIngestionTime
```

However this fails because `.delete` doesn't allow `summarize` in the predicate. I tried getting around this by doing the `summarize` in a separate query and materializing it like so:

```
let maxingest = materialize(TABLENAME
| summarize MaxIngestionTime = max(ingestion_time()) by Key);

.delete table TABLENAME records <| TABLENAME
| join kind=inner (maxingest) on Key
| where ingestion_time() != MaxIngestionTime
```

But this doesn't work either as it says that it can't resolve table or column expression "maxingest". Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution that requires sorting the table by Key and then `ingestion_time()` and the assigning each record an index form 1 to n where `n` is the number of duplicates that you get. The challenge is that you can't introduce new columns and are limited by the specific functions you can call.

Here is a sample table creation script where you ingest duplicated keys into the table:

```
.create-merge table SampleTest (
    Key: int,
    Content: string
);

.append SampleTest <|
datatable(Key: int, Content: string) [
    1, "a",
    2, "b"
]

.append SampleTest <|
datatable(Key: int, Content: string) [
    1, "c",
    2, "d"
]
```

Here is how you delete the duplicated records, keeping the latest ones only:

```
.delete table SampleTest records  <| 
SampleTest
| sort by Key, ingestion_time() desc
| where row_cumsum(1,prev(Key) !=Key) > 1
```

Here is what is happening:

- First you serialize the records by sorting the rows by the unique `Key`, and then the `ingestion_time()` in descending order
- Next you use the `where` clause and use the `row_cumsum` function to create an index variable. This variable increments by 1 for every record, and resets to 1 if the `Key` changes. Only the latest record will have a value of 1 so the duplicates are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [materialized views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview). You can deduplicate using an `arg_max()` or `take_any()` aggregation. See examples in the [use cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-use-cases) page.

Comment: Thanks @yifats, but I'm not sure if materialized views will make sense here. We want to be able to delete duplicate records after incidents where our data processing pipeline has issues, which would need us to replay some data through the pipeline. We're not sure if the performance hit from constantly having a materialized view running is worth it when these duplicates from replaying should be a rare event.